# Keyboard and mouse stop working in Ubuntu, can only do REISUB

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I was using Ubuntu 23.04 on my Lenovo Legion Laptop (AMD 5600H + RTX3060) and was in tty when the computer suddenly stopped responding to any keyboard input. I thought the system has frozen and used Alt+SysRq+REISUB to reboot. But after the reboot my system no longer recognizes keyboard or mouse anymore in normal mode.

SDDM will show a virtual keyboard automatically as if no keyboard is detected. If I enable autologin to /etc/SDDM.conf, the system will get into Plasma Wayland desktop. Plasma widgets like clock/notifications will all work properly on my laptop's built-in monitor but frozen on the external monitor connected through USB-C cable (I have no HDMI cable and can't test if monitor will work on other cables).

As my laptop's touchpad and keyboard are both using PS/2 interface, it's probably not only a USB driver issue.

Only MagickSysRq still worked on normal bootup (tested with Kernel 6.2.0-25 and 6.2.0-20). The keyboard will work properly in recovery mode.